# Reverse only vowels in Linked List of characters

Tags: python, algorithm, linked-list

For example I have a singly linked list 'a' --> 'b' --> 'q' --> 'o' --> 'r' --> 'e'

How to reverse only vowels, so the list would look like this: 'e' --> 'b' --> 'q' --> 'o' --> 'r' --> 'a' ?

Comment: Suggestion: Push the vowels in stack for the first iteration. On second iteration replace all the vowels with stack.top() and pop the stack element.

Comment: how did you do it when you wrote the question? Do the same in code

Comment: @idclev 463035818 the same in code is possible with doubly linked list, but I don't want to rewrite my code into double linked list, so I want to know ,maybe someone has ideas how to solve this using singly linked list

Comment: This is possible. But could you clarify in your question what the rules are? (1) Is it allowed to convert the list to array, do the action in the array, and then convert it back to linked list? (2) If not, is it allowed to store the nodes that have vowels in an array/stack, and then use that to make the reversal? (3) If not, is it allowed to only exchange the *values* of the nodes, and leave the nodes in place? (4) Is it allowed to use recursion (which is a hidden form of use of stack)? This question becomes really interesting if none of this is allowed, but the rules should be mentioned.

Comment: And: (5) Can the linked list implementation have a sentinel node and be circular?

Answer (score 1):

I will make the following assumptions:

- The reversal should not alter the node's *values*, but really move the involved node *objects*
- The algorithm should use *constant* extra space. So this excludes the use of an array, a stack, recursion, another linked list, ...etc to temporarily keep track of the nodes that need to be moved.

### 1. Proposed algorithm

The rough idea is to:

1. Find the *first* and *last* occurrence of a vowel in the linked list
2. If no two distinct nodes are found, end the algorithm
3. Swap the two nodes that were identified. To make the swap possible, we need to keep track of the two nodes that *precede* the matching nodes.
4. Repeat from step 1, but only search in the middle range of the list that is *between* the two nodes that were identified and swapped in the current iteration.

As this middle range will get smaller and smaller, the algorithm is guaranteed to end.

The swap function will need to deal with some special cases:

- If the two nodes to swap are adjacent, special care needs to be taken to do a correct "rewiring"
- If the first node is also the very first node of the list (i.e. its head), then we don't really have its *preceding* node. So this is also a special case to deal with. I will suggest to treat the linked list object to be a special (valueless) node, so that in this case the preceding node can be actually the list object. See below.

### 2. Linked List implementation

The core linked list implementation could look like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next


class LinkedList(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        # LinkedList is implemented as a sentinel Node. 
        # Its next property represents the head 
        # We provide some dummy value ("HEAD"), but that should never be used
        super().__init__("HEAD")

    # Create a new Node for the given value and add it in front of the list
    def prepend(self, val):
        self.next = Node(val, self.next)

    # Create new Nodes for each value in the sequence and prepend them to the list
    def prependsequence(self, seq):
        for val in reversed(seq):
            self.prepend(val)
    
    # Iterate the values in the list
    def __iter__(self):
        node = self.next
        while node:
            yield node.val
            node = node.next
```

This defines `Node` and `LinkedList`. I have opted to let `LinkedList` inherit from `Node`, so that it also has a `next` attribute, which in other implementations would have been called `head` instead. But I like the similarity with `Node`: the linked list object now acts like a kind of [sentinel node](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node), although that term is more applicable to doubly linked lists. The benefit is clear: code becomes simpler as it rarely needs to differentiate between a "real" node and the list object. A "real" node now always has a preceding node. In particular, the *first* node of a list will have the list object as its predecessor.

With this implementation you can create a list, add new nodes in front of it, and iterate the values that are in it. For example:

```
a = LinkedList()
a.prependsequence("facetious")  # add all these letters in one go
print(list(a))  # ['f', 'a', 'c', 'e', 't', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's']
```

### 3. Implementation of the algorithm

The above implementation is extended with a few more methods:

```
    # Find the first occurrence of a value in the given range of the list
    def find(self, condition, prev=None, last=None):
        if not prev:
            prev = self  # the list object serves as a sentinel node
        while prev != last and prev.next:
            if condition(prev.next.val):
                return prev
            prev = prev.next

    # Find the first and last occurrence of a value in the given range of the list
    def findfirstlast(self, condition, prev=None, last=None):
        prev1 = prev2 = found = self.find(condition, prev, last)
        while found:
            prev2, found = found, self.find(condition, found.next, last)
        # return the nodes that precede the matching two nodes
        #  if not found: None, None
        #  if only one match found: prev1 == prev2   
        return prev1, prev2

    # Swap the nodes that follow the given two nodes
    def swap(self, prev1, prev2):
        if prev1 == prev2:
            return
        if prev2.next == prev1:  # adjacent nodes given in opposite order
            prev1, prev2 = prev2, prev1
        node1, node2 = prev1.next, prev2.next
        if node1 == prev2:  # adjacent nodes
            prev2.next, node2.next = node2.next, node1
        else:  # not adjacent nodes
            prev2.next, node2.next, node1.next  = node1, node1.next, node2.next
        prev1.next = node2
```

So we have methods to find node(s) based on a condition. That condition should be a callback function that will return a boolean indicating whether the node matches the condition or not. For instance, the condition for finding vowels would be:

```
lambda val: val in "aeiouAEIOU"
```

These find-methods accept optional arguments to indicate where to start and stop the search. This way we can limit the search to a sub list within the linked list.

Note that the `prev` argument is the node that *precedes* the first node that is within that search range. And the function returns node(s) that *precede* the matching nodes. This is needed to allow the caller to potentially rewire the list to remove or replace the matching nodes.

The `swap` method performs such a rewiring. So it also needs the two nodes that *precede* the nodes to swap. Remember that a preceding node could be the linked list object itself, which means that the head of the list will be swapped.

With these basic operations, the algorithm can be implemented with one additional method:

```
    # The method that performs the requested task based on a callback function
    def reversewhen(self, condition):
        prev1, prev2 = self.findfirstlast(condition)
        while prev1 != prev2:
            self.swap(prev1, prev2)
            prev1, prev2 = self.findfirstlast(condition, prev1.next, prev2)
```

The `while` condition will not be true when either there is no match (`prev1` and `prev2` will both be `None`) or there is just one match (`prev1` and `prev2` will both be that single match). The latter happens when there are an odd number of matching nodes in the overall list: the middle one of these does not have to move.

Note how in general `prev1` and `prev2` are node references that come closer to each other as more iterations are performed.

Here is a sample execution of this method:

```
a = LinkedList()
a.prependsequence("facetious")
print(list(a))  # ['f', 'a', 'c', 'e', 't', 'i', 'o', 'u', 's']
isvowel = lambda val: val in "aeiouAEIOU"
a.reversewhen(isvowel)
print(list(a))  # ['f', 'u', 'c', 'o', 't', 'i', 'e', 'a', 's']
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq641397295459839)

### 4. Time Complexity

Because of the self-imposed restrictions on extra space, the algorithm's time complexity cannot be *O(n)*. In the worst case (almost) all nodes have vowels, and so the number of iterations of the main loop, combined with the number iterations needed in the search for matching nodes, give this algorithm a time complexity of *O(n²)*.

To get a time complexity of *O(n)* you'll need to use *O(n)* space. If that is preferred, then put all nodes in an array, use two indexes in that array moving from both ends towards each other, and swap nodes that match. Finally rewire the nodes in the array in one sweep, and update the linked list to have the first node in the array as its head. This is quite trivial and ... feels like cheating. It really solves an array based problem instead of a linked list based problem. So I didn't go for that.

Answer (score -1):

The solution of the problem in different languages ​​is available on the following site:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/swap-the-vowels-in-the-linked-list-representation-of-a-string/

Comment: That is a different problem. *"swap every subsequent pair of vowels"* is not the same as reversing the vowels.